# PLINK.EXE: use blowfish as the cipher

Tags: ssh, putty

Is it possible to use blowfish as the cipher of [PLINK.EXE](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)? For OpenSSH, the `-c` option can be used to specify the cipher, but how to do it with PLINK.EXE?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from PuTTY documentation :

> Not all features are accessible from the command line yet, although
>   we'd like to fix this. In the meantime, you can use most of PuTTY's
>   features if you create a PuTTY saved session, and then use the name
>   of the saved session on the command line in place of a hostname.